# Excel plot with dynamic series based on column values

Tags: excel, plot, series

I don't know exactly how to phrase this but I am essentially hoping to group data into series for an excel plot based on a column value preceding the other data. For example:

```
       size weight
apple   3   35
orange  4   63
banana  5   43
apple   5   32
apple   4   123
orange  4   21
banana  3   23
```

If I had this data I would want the result to be a scatter plot graph with all the apples in one series, all of the oranges in their own series etc with size on the X and weight on the Y. I have been trying messing around with pivot tables, but I get stuck since it provides averages/counts and not every single data point. I know how to do this manually adding one series at a time using sorting, but I was hoping there might be some easier way to expedite the process since it seems so straightforward.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable may help you if you add an index column and use that for Row labels (forcing Σ Values to treat each row individually). You can't plot a scatter chart from a PT so I copied the body of the PT instead and pasted Special as Values:

[image: SO19709189 example]